# Where is the QML map cache stored in ubuntu / windows?

Tags: qt, qml, qt5

I need to load my cache from my PC in other PC. So, where is the qml map cache in PC? When my app is working on ubuntu 20.04 I found cache in ./cache/myproject/qmlcache. But when I removed the cache from there while the program was running, it still displayed the map correctly. Where is the real map cache stored?

Comment: Are you loading map through Qml WebEngine or Map component?
Please provide some sample code for the approach you are trying. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be under /.cache/QtLocation or /.cache/<app_name>/QtLocation

The subdirectory depends on the [plugin you use for the map tiles](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtlocation-index.html#plugin-references-and-parameters).

[/qmlcache is just the cache for the QML engine itself](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmldiskcache.html), not the tiles.